# Is there an equivalent to __attribute__((ns_returns_retained)) for a malloc'd pointer?

Tags: objective-c, c, clang, static-analysis

I'm looking for an annotation something like

```
-(SomeStruct *) structFromInternals __attribute__((returns_malloced_ptr))
{
    SomeStruct *ret = malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct));
    //do stuff
    return ret;
}
```

to soothe the clang static analyzer beasts.
The only viable attributes link I can find is [for GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), but it doesn't even include `ns_returns_retained`, which is in an extension, I assume.

EDIT:

as to why this is needed, I have a scenario that I can't repro in a simple case, so it may have to do with a c lib in an Objective-C project... The gist is, I get a static analyzer warning that the malloc in createStruct is leaked:

```
typedef struct{
    void * data;
    size_t len;
}MyStruct;

void destroyStruct(MyStruct * s)
{
    if (s && s->data) {
        free(s->data);
    }
    if (s) {
        free(s);
    }
}
MyStruct * createStructNoCopy(size_t len, void * data)
{
    MyStruct * retStruct = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
    retStruct->len = len;
    retStruct->data = data;
    return retStruct;
}
MyStruct * createStruct(size_t len, void * data)
{
    char * tmpData = malloc(len);
    memcpy(tmpData, data, len);
    return createStructNoCopy(len, tmpData);
}
MyStruct * copyStruct(MyStruct * s)
{
    return createStruct(s->len, s->data);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Just write it in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function annotation `ownership_returns(malloc)` will tell the Clang static analyser that the function returns a pointer that should be passed to `free()` at some point (or a function with `ownership_takes(malloc, ...)`). For example:

```
void __attribute((ownership_returns(malloc))) *my_malloc(size_t);
void __attribute((ownership_takes(malloc, 1))) my_free(void *);
...
void af1() {
    int *p = my_malloc(1);
    return; // expected-warning{{Potential leak of memory pointed to by}}
}
void af2() {
    int *p = my_malloc(1);
    my_free(p);
    return; // no-warning
}
```

(See the [`malloc-annotations.c` test file](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/test/Analysis/malloc-annotations.c?view=markup) for some more examples of their use.)

At the moment, these annotations only take effect when the `alpha.unix.MallocWithAnnotations` checker is run (which is not run by default). If you're using Xcode, you'll need to add `-Xclang -analyzer-checker=alpha.unix.MallocWithAnnotations` to your build flags.