# Clang Annotations for Unix.malloc Static Analysis

Tags: xcode, annotations, clang, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

I have C code that looks like the following.  The function `takeString()` is known to take ownership of its malloc-ed pointer argument.  The Clang static analyzer will complain that `string` is a potential memory leak at `return 0` in `main()`.  Strictly for C code, what annotation can I apply, ideally in the declaration of `takeString()`, that will inform the Clang Static Analyzer that `string` won't be leaked?

```
#define OwnershipTaken(type)        type

void takeString (OwnershipTaken(char *) string) {
  // ... eventually frees
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  char *string = strdup ("This is a string");
  takeString (string);

  return 0;
}
```

A more general question is where can I see the list of all possible annotations that the Clang static analyzer understands?

I've tried using annotations like `void __attribute((ownership_takes(malloc, 1))) takeString(char *);` but this does not seem to change the result. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16290023/1286639) notes that `unix.MallocWithAnnotations` needs to be enabled.  How is that done in Xcode? However, the current version of Xcode does not appear to include `unix.MallocWithAnnotations`.

Comment: Do you have the implementation of `takeString` in the same compilation unit? If so, are you sure you call `free()` there? Because the only way I can reproduce the leak warning is when there's no `free()`.

Comment: It is not in the same compilation unit.

Comment: Do you have a working example you could share? Cannot reproduce this. Created the `takeString` in a static library and ran the `main` with linking, and no errors.

Comment: In your case, shouldn't the Analyzer have complained that 'string is leaked'?  It has no info about your library's implementation of `takeString` - how does the Analyzer know that `string` is actually freed?  If you use `free` in your `takeString`; what if you remove `free` - will the Analyzer complain?  Thanks!

Comment: @GoZoner I agree, since there was no free in my `takeString` 'string is leaked' was my expectations as well. That’s why I asked for an example. How you run this in Xcode (or in terminal), what Analyzer parameters/flags and how the `takeString` is compiled as a different compilation unit than main. Would be easier to help out if I could reproduce it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what I believe you are looking to do it's possible via the [`analyzer_noreturn`](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html) attribute.

```
#ifndef CLANG_ANALYZER_RELEASED
#if __has_feature(attribute_analyzer_noreturn)
#define CLANG_ANALYZER_RELEASED __attribute__((analyzer_noreturn))
#else
#define CLANG_ANALYZER_RELEASED
#endif
#endif

// suppress the leak warning for `string`.

void takeString(char *) CLANG_ANALYZER_RELEASED;
```

To see a complete list of clang static analyzer checkers:

```
$ clang -cc1 -analyzer-checker-help
```

> *<sub>`alpha.unix.MallocWithAnnotations` does not appear to be present in most recent versions of llvm.</sub>

To enable/disable checkers, and set the options: (Xcode `Build Settings` > `Other C Flags`)

```
OTHER_CFLAGS = -D__clang_analyzer__ -Xclang -analyzer-output=plist-html -Xclang -analyzer-config -Xclang path-diagnostics-alternate=true -Xclang -analyzer-config -Xclang report-in-main-source-file=true -Xclang -analyzer-config -Xclang mode=shallow -Xclang -analyzer-config -Xclang osx.NumberObjectConversion:Pedantic=true -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.UncheckedReturn -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.getpw -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.gets -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.mkstemp -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.mktemp -Xclang -analyzer-disable-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.rand -Xclang -analyzer-disable-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.strcpy -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang security.insecureAPI.vfork -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang osx.cocoa.RetainCount -Xclang -analyzer-checker -Xclang osx.cocoa.Dealloc
```

↳ [Clang static analyzer checkers not present in Xcode 10](https://gist.github.com/ParityError/40e1a242ed1306a2e1bc89da4e186f4b#file-clang-analyzer-checkers-9-0-md)

Comment: `CLANG_ANALYZER_RELEASED` applies to the whole function, it seems.  I need the 'release annotation' to be argument specific.

Comment: @GoZoner: The name `CLANG_ANALYZER_RELEASED` can be anything (that’s just what i named it); the annotation `analyzer_noreturn` is what is doing the work, and yes, it unfortunately only applies to functions, methods and blocks. I’m not sure you’ll find anything in terms of a non-specific obj-c annotation that can be set to just a variable or pointer.

Comment: @GoZoner: You could make `string` a global variable and then likely won’t receive the warning. I realize that’s probably what you wish to avoid, but it might serve as a temporary solution perhaps. The only other suggestion that comes to mind would be to compile an older version of `llvm` which includes the `alpha.unix.MallocWithAnnotations` checker.